# Unable to exclude non-capturing groups in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-group

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?:&nbsp;)?\((\w+)\)$");
var value = "&nbsp;(HTML)";

//I tried to play around with the following but it captures the whole string
var match = ResourceTypeRegex.Match(resourceType);

//The following lines all evaluate to the entire string
match.Groups.OfType<Group>().SingleOrDefault();
match.Captures.OfType<Capture>().SingleOrDefault();
match.Groups[0].Captures.OfType<Capture>().SingleOrDefault();
```

I only want to capture `HTML` or whatever string it is.

Comment: Have you considered using an XML/HTML parser instead? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1808494

Comment: @Aron, I am, and I'm using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Anyway this is an `HtmlTextNode` that the string I'm referring to is returned by its `InnerHtml` property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is a bit wrong perhaps?  The following will return **HTML**.  Your regex is missing the second capture.

```
var ResourceTypeRegex = new Regex(@"^(?: )?\((\w+)\)$");
var value = "&nbsp;(HTML)";

var match = ResourceTypeRegex.Match(value);

Console.WriteLine("'" + match.Groups[1] + "'");
```

To get at the capture, start with index 1 using the Groups array.

I am not sure why you want to use LINQ on this but since you insist, you can create this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> CapturingGroups(this GroupCollection c) {     
    var query = c.OfType<Group>().Select(g => g.Value);

    //We only want index 1 and over since 0 is actually the entire string
    //if (c.Count > 1)
        query = query.Skip(1);

    return query;
}
```

And instead of using `match.Groups[1]`, you can change it to `Console.WriteLine("'{0}'",match.Groups.CapturingGroups().FirstOrDefault());`

Running example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/097fo9

Comment: I only want to capture `HTML` or whatever string it is.

Comment: Simple enough, change the regex to: var ResourceTypeRegex = new Regex(@"^(?: )?\((\w+)\)$");  Now it will ignore the enclosing ().  Updated the dotnetfiddle for working example.

Comment: So isn't there a way to refer only to capturing groups i.e. `match.CapturingGroups.SingleOrDefault()`? Please always wrap code snippets in `\`` quotes, also in comments.

Comment: As stribizhev mentioned... AFAIK, you can either use index based or if named capture as per MariusZ answer, you can use the named given to the capture group.  I don't think you can use LINQ to parse this unless you go out of your way to dump the captures into a proper array, perhaps using extension method and then use Linq on that. see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you're last code is an error because `mach.Groups[1]` is not `match.Groups.FirstOrDefault()`, and the `ToList()` can be replaced with `OfType<Group>()`, anyway I've made some changes to your post.

Comment: I ended up using `match.Groups.OfType<Group>().Last();`. Thanks

Comment: I missed two things: 1) missed those parenthesis in my regex 2) I didn't know that the first capturing group will always be the entire string. And hey, LINQ is part of the language ages ago. Why not keep things less verbose? And it will also perform faster than `ToList`, especially if I'm to perform other upcoming refinements. The advantage of IEnumerable is that it's [executed deferred](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669162.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

All the examples below will return `HTML` right after `&nbsp;(` and before the `)` at the end of the string.

`(?<=&nbsp;\))` is a look-behind that ensures we have `&nbsp;(` before `HTML` (but does not add it to the captured result). `(?=\)$)` is a positive look-ahead checking if we have `)` at the end of the string (`$`). Again, the `)` is not consumed, and is not part of the match.

```
Regex ResourceTypeRegex = new Regex(@"^(?:&nbsp;\()?(\w+)(?=\)$)");
var value = "&nbsp;(HTML)";
var result56 = ResourceTypeRegex.Match(value).Groups[1].Value;
```

The output is `HTML` with no round brackets. The `(?:&nbsp;\()?` makes the `&nbsp;)` optional.

If you use `.SingleOrDefault()`, it will only return the 0th capture group, that is equal to **entire match**.

Comment: I only want to capture `HTML` or whatever string it is.

Comment: I edited the answer, now, the round brackets will not be part of the return string.

Comment: Notice that the first group is optional. Anyway isn't there a way to refer only to capturing groups i.e. `match.CapturingGroups.SingleOrDefault()`?

Comment: Yes, you can. Only use them like this: `regex.Match(input).Groups[1].Value`.

Comment: No, I don't want to refer to the groups by their index. I only want to refer to **capturing groups**, if I won't have a choice I'll just use a named group, that's what I usually do, but once and for all I'm asking this question to learn about this precise issue.

Comment: You should know then that there is always the 0th capturing group which equals to the whole match. To obtain the necessary capture group, you should either address it by index (starting by 1) or by name (if you use a named capturing group). See the last sentence in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var match = Regex.Match(inputString, @"^&nbsp;\((?<yourMatch>.*?)\)$");
var value = match.Groups["yourMatch"].Value;
```